# Making a frequency distribution using intervals

Tags: statistics, histogram

I am trying to get help with a statistics problem. It is not advanced by any means and I know very well how to solve it. I just happened to stumble across LaTeX and got interested in learning how to use it, and as the assignment I am currently working on is rather simple I thought this would be the perfect time to try to learn LaTeX. The assignment is as follows:[image]

I Currently have this piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Statistikk og Risikoanalyse 1}
\author{Isak Midtvedt}
\date{22.01.2022}



\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l | l |}
        Speed interval & Frequency\\
        \hline \hline
        0.45-0.90 & 2\\
        0.90-1.35 & 6\\
        1.35-1.80 & 11\\
        1.80-2.25 & 5\\
        2.25-2.70 & 6
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Frequencies}
       \label{tab:week1}
\end{table}
```

Which produces this result;

[image]

Now what would be the best way, using the frequency table I already drew to make a histogram? Is there a way for latex to pull the data or do I have to do it manually? And if so, how do I go about doing it? Cheers

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i tried copying a answer from someone else where they made a histogram from a csv file. But I didnt understand how to handle the distribution. Or rather how to classify what number goes where etc. Is there a universal good tutorial about histograms or pgfplots in general someone could reccomend?

Comment: Please, post code that we can copy and paste, not an image of code.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Updated the question to be more concise and also easier for someone to "get into"

Comment: Have you looked at the [`pgfplots` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgfplots/0)? Histograms are described in section 5.12.2 (in the manual for version 1.18.1).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes and I have made a lot of progress, the only thing that is missing now is getting the right intervals. I have defined it as needing 6 "bins" and I have define xmax and xmin as 2.7 and 0.45, but the interval is not 0.45, it is currently 0.37 and I dont understand the manual well enough to understand what variable to add/change

Comment: Why do you expect the interval/bin width to be 0.45 with 6 bins from 0.45 to 2.7? (2.7 - 0.45)/6 = 0.375

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Badly worded by me. The assignment states that you should split the data in 0.45 intervals, 0.45-0.90, 0.90-1.35 and so on. By defining xmax as 2.7, 0.45 goes into that 6 times. So i thought that was how it worked. Regardless I just need the X label to say 0.45-0.90 and so on. And also for the histogram to distribute correctly with the given requirements

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am tired and also apparently very stupid. Thank you for the answer. I figured it out now. I just need to set bins to 5 and then it will go up (2.7-0.45)/5 = 0.45. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

The first question you had is done just going through the manual and setting it up the way you want. With respect to your other 2 questions: "Is there a way for latex to pull the data or do I have to do it manually? And if so, how do I go about doing it?" the answer is yes. One way to do it is with the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en) package which gives you access to the CAS Sage which allows for Python programming as well. Basic statistics documentation is [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/stats/sage/stats/basic_stats.html).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,tikz,pgfplots,xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Statistikk og Risikoanalyse 1}
\author{Isak Midtvedt}
\date{22.01.2022}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{sagesilent}
MyData = [1.28,1.36,1.24, 2.47,1.94,2.52,2.67,1.29,1.56,2.66,2.17,1.57,2.10,2.54,1.63,2.11,2.57,1.72,0.76,1.02,1.78,0.50,1.49,1.57,1.04,1.92,1.55,1.78,1.70,1.20]
bins = 5
step = .45
frequencies =[0 for i in range(0,bins)]

for i in range(0,len(MyData)):
    for j in range(0,bins):
        if MyData[i]<.45+(j+1)*.45 and MyData[i]>=.45+j*.45:
            frequencies[j] += 1

output = r"\begin{table}[h]"
output += r"\centering"
output += r"\begin{tabular}{l | l |}"
output += r"Speed interval & Frequency\\"
output += r"\hline \hline"
for i in range(0,bins):
    if i < bins-1:
        output += r"%.2f-%.2f & %d\\"%(.45+i*.45, .45+(i+1)*.45, frequencies[i])
    else:
        output += r"%.2f-%.2f & %d"%(.45+i*.45, .45+(i+1)*.45, frequencies[i])
output += r"\end{tabular}"
output += r"\caption{Frequencies}"
output += r"\label{tab:week1}"
output += r"\end{table}"
output += r"\begin{center}"
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\begin{axis}[title = My Histogram,ybar interval,ymin=0, ymax=12,minor y tick num = 1,area style]"
output += r"\addplot coordinates {"
for i in range(0,bins):
    output += r"(%.2f,%d)"%(.45+i*step,frequencies[i])
output += r"(%.2f,%d)"%(.45+bins*step,0)
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\end{center}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

Running the code in Cocalc gives the following result:
[image]

On the basis of `MyData` and the five bins you wanted to create, Sage creates the frequency table and then the histogram. This makes mistakes less likely, especially as the amount of data increases.

Sage is not part of the Latex distribution. The easiest way to access it is through a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. It's also possible to download the program to your computer; however, this can be problematic depending on your computer and computer expertise. If there is lots of mathematics/statistics in your life, Sage and `sagetex` can solve a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{statistics}
\begin{document}
    \StatsRangeData \tips = { 1.28, 1.36, 1.24, 2.47, 1.94, 2.52, 2.67, 1.29, 1.56, 2.66, 2.17, 1.57, 2.10, 2.54, 1.63, 2.11, 2.57, 1.72, 0.76, 1.02, 1.78, 0.50, 1.49, 1.57, 1.04, 1.92, 1.55, 1.78, 1.70, 1.20 }
    (\IN[0.45;0.90;[, \IN[0.90;1.35;[, \IN[1.35;1.80;[, \IN[1.80;2.25;[, \IN[2.25;2.70;])
    %\detokenize\expandafter{\tips}
    \statisticssetup{table/values=Classes}
    \statisticssetup[table]{counts=Counts}
    \statisticssetup[table]{frequencies=Frequencies}    
    
    \StatsTable \tips
    
    \statisticssetup{graph/values=Classes}
    \statisticssetup[graph]{counts=Counts}
    \StatsGraph \tips[x/axis = {ticks={major={at={0.45, 0.9, 1.35,1.80,2.25,2.7}}}, grid = none}, y/axis = {grid = none},axissystem={end labels, clean}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Table and Histogram]